# Cannot get image on Docker - Network timed out [Windows]

Tags: docker

I just downloaded docker and when I run `docker run hello-world` I get `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/respositories/library/hello-world/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy`

My internet is connected and I'm not behind a proxy. I've looked up other answer to this, but they either do not work or are specific to unix-based systems.

I'm running Windows 10 and downloaded Docker Toolbox using the `.exe` installer from here https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v1.12.5

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why don't you use Docker for Windows which run natively?

Comment: @JanshairKhan because when I try to do that, I get the error `Hyper-V is not available on home editions. Please use docker toolbox.`

Comment: Personally, I also confronted the same issue when I used Docker prior 1.12 on VirtualBox. I tried to switch to a different Internet (with a faster speed) and it got worked. It had not worked with my home Internet but worked at my campus's Internet.